# Getting Google+ subscription count with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter, google-plus, subscription

Is possible to get the total number of Google+ subscriptions in same way was done on http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/google_plus_one_api_example.php? Without php?

Thanks

update: i tried with this piece of code but isn't working

```
function getplusone(url){
     var plusones;
     $.getJSON('https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ' + 'callback=?',
        {
           "method":"pos.plusones.get",
           "id":"p",
           "params":{
              "nolog":true,
              "id":url,
              "source":"widget",
              "userId":"@viewer",
              "groupId":"@self"
           },
           "jsonrpc":"2.0",
           "key":"p",
           "apiVersion":"v1"
        },
        function(data){           
        plusones = data.count;
        $('#feed').html(plusones);
     });
  }
```

Comment: i don't quite know how to use properly an API. I was wondering if someone know a snippet or something like that. regards.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create a API Key from Google Console - https://console.developers.google.com

Then you need to get the Page or Profile Id for which you need to get the followers/subscribers count.

After that you need to send a request to this url-
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{PROFILE_ID}?key={APIKEY}

Using the below code-

```
var profileid = 'YOUR_PROFILE_ID';
var apikey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/' + profileid + '?key=' + apikey;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        var googlefollowcount = data.circledByCount;
        $(".googlefollowercount").html(googlefollowcount);
    }
});
```

The request will be send like this one above but make sure that you replace your Profile ID and API key.

You can see and follow the whole process from this url-
http://www.bloggerever.com/2014/05/how-can-you-get-google-plus-follower.html

Answer (score 1):

The response data is usually represented in JSON format. Generally, you can receive the desired data through a server's API method, jQuery features an ability of sending such requests. It should look something like this

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://example.org/method/getInformation",
    data: { uid: "1232", fields: name,lastname,photo,subscriptions, access_token: "1224beca124"},
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

All the data is just for example. Note that if you send requests from your server to Google+'s server, you need to use attribute dataType: "jsonp", since it is a way that cross-domain requests are handled. Note also that you may or you may not need a token (granted through authentication system, like OAuth) for some kind of information.

Comment: i tried with the code from question (updated), but isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ",
    data: [{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"http://www.test.com","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}],
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

It's the standard jQuery [ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). You need dataType: "jsonp" because it's a cross-domain request, and you need type: "POST" as in the [blog post](http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/google_plus_one_button_seo_count_api/) from the example you provided. However, when I try it, it returns an object with state = "rejected" and I suppose this is because the key is no longer valid. If you have your own valid key it should work.

Comment: thanks, but not sure how to post the data into a div with id "feed" to test it.

Comment: You can use something like $('#feed').text(JSON.parse(data));. Or if you are using chrome open dev tools (F12 on windows/option+command+i on mac), go to the sources tab and put a breakpoint in the script on the line where data is received. When you refresh the page the execution will pause at the breakpoint and you can inspect the value of data by hovering over it.