# Requesting +1 google shares with jQuery.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-plus, share

Im trying to get the google plus shares via ajax, i do this with the facebook and the twitter URL, but the google not provide a clear way to do the request, and i'm not being successful.

Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyB0mMLOeNCXUInw-sbS5SOf5l3oWCaxE8M",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
                method: "pos.plusones.get",
                id: "p",
                params: {
                        nolog: true,
                        id: "ohmybeer.d.flowecommerce.com/cervejas.html",
                        source: "widget",
                        userId: "@viewer",
                        groupId: "@self"
                },
                jsonrpc: "2.0",
                key: "p",
                apiVersion: "v1"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('error');
            console.log("error");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

I have research how to achieve, but i not resolved this. I have see a lot of similar question about the same subject, but none of the answers help me successfully. As result i receive the following json:

```
{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Invalid parameter: callback","data":[{"domain":"global","reason":"invalidParameter","message":"Invalid parameter: callback","locationType":"parameter","location":"callback"}]},"id":"p"}
```

i've followed this tutorial and question(and many others not so relevant):
https://gist.github.com/jonathanmoore/2640302,
[Getting Google+ subscription count with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424640/getting-google-subscription-count-with-jquery)

some say that do this request from client side is not possible, but others did achieve this like the code in the tutorial, someone can give me any help?
I got my api-key from the google+ api on the console of google apis.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: It looks like the examples use GET while you are using POST.

Comment: It's true, but i also did a lot of tests using GET instead of POST and the result still is the same... Do you have any other solution? Tanks.

Comment: There is an API [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=57) for an official API you can star.

Comment: @Aquilla did you manage to figure this out? as I am having the same problem