# Getting google +1 Page shares via AJAX (hidden Api)

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, google-plus

Struggling to find the solution for getting the **Google Plus +1 of page** via jQuery - Ajax from Google's hidden api: https://clients6.google.com/rpc

This issue is also discussed at: [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424640/getting-google-subscription-count-with-jquery)

My attempt:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://clients6.google.com/rpc",
    data: [{
        "method":"pos.plusones.get",
        "id":"p",
        "params":{
            "nolog":true,
            "id":"http://www.apple.com",
            //"id":"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.apple.com",
            "source":"widget",
            "userId":"@viewer",
            "groupId":"@self"
            },
            "jsonrpc":"2.0",
            "key":"p",
            "apiVersion":"v1"
    }],
    crossDomain: true,
    jsonp: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    always: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

With result in chrome: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

And in Firefox:
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

{"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse Error","data":[{"domain":"g

**Any ideas how to solve this?**

Answer (score 5):

You can use the google plus javascript library to get the share count:

Include these:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js"></script>
```

Then do:

```
var params = {
  nolog: true,
  id: "http://www.google.com/",
  source: "widget",
  userId: "@viewer",
  groupId: "@self"
};

gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ')
gapi.client.rpcRequest('pos.plusones.get', 'v1', params).execute(function(resp) {
  console.log('count:', resp.result.metadata.globalCounts.count)
});
```

Don't replace the apikey with your own. If you do it won't work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The gapi.client should be initialized? I'm receiving an error: TypeError: gapi.client is undefined

Comment: You can add a callback to know if the js library has loaded: `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js?onload=onLoadCallback"></script>`. More info here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript

Comment: The callback doesn't work for me either. For testing purposes, I can get it to work by manually triggering the gapi call. However, despite getting the count, I also get a deprecation warning. o, this approach may stop working completely in the non too far future.

Comment: Also, it's pretty ugly how many requests the Google API is doing for retrieving the +1 count. Shame on you, Google!

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the official API for Google+ to get +1 counts for pages.  The following example from the APIs explorer shows the API call and response data:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get?userId=%252BGooglePlusDevelopers&fields=plusOneCount&_h=2&

A short demo of how to use the API client library:

1) Async include of the Google+ client / Google API client library

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  var po = document.createElement('script');
  po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
  po.src = 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
</script>
```

When the client loads, set the API key with a key from the [Google APIs console](http://code.google.com/apis/console):

```
gapi.client.setApiKey('YOUR_API_KEY')
```

Next, load the callback and place an API call once the client is loaded.

```
<script>
gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', 
  function(){ 
    gapi.client.plus.people.get(
      {userId: '+GooglePlusDevelopers'}
    ).execute( function(resp){ console.log(resp); }
    );
  });
</script>
```

This will return JSON data that includes the +1 count, e.g.:

```
gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', 
  function(){ 
    gapi.client.plus.people.get(
      {userId: '+GooglePlusDevelopers'}
    ).execute( function(resp){ console.log(resp.plusOneCount); }
    );
  });
```

Will return 225588, the count of +1s for the page.