# How to get google plus button count via AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-plus

I searched hours for a working solution to get google plus button count via js call.

this is my solution:

```
<script>
function handleClientLoad(){
    var params = {
        nolog: true,
        id: "http://www.google.de/",
        source: "widget",
        userId: "@viewer",
        groupId: "@self"
    };

    gapi.client.rpcRequest('pos.plusones.get', 'v1', params).execute(function(resp) {
        console.log('count:', resp.result.metadata.globalCounts.count)
    });
}

</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[THIS](http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/google_plus_one_button_seo_count_api/)  link may be you, example have php curl example but curl URL can also call with JS ajax.

**EDIT**

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ",
        data: {"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"' . $url . '","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"} ,
dataType : json
        success: function(res){

           console.log(res);
        //[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count']
        }
    });
```

Comment: this works in PHP, but not with JS. To make it work with JS use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524077/getting-google-1-page-shares-via-ajax-hidden-api