# Get Google+ shares without API key for each page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, google-plus

On a search result page I would like to get the count of Google+ shares for the URL of each search result item via Ajax. I already managed to set up counting functions for Facebook and Twitter:

```
    $.getJSON('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' + url + '&callback=?', function(data){
        tweets = data.count;
    });

    $.getJSON('https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls='+ url+'&format=json', function(data){
        fblikes = data[url].shares;
    });
```

For Google+ I also already found a solution, but this requires the API Key for each URL. Is there any way to retrieve the Google+ count without such a key? Using it for tons of dynamically loaded search results, of course I cannot create an API key for each search result URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to get Google +1 counts. They are retrieved via a JSON-RPC POST call.

POST URL:

```
https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ
```

POST Body:

`[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"%%URL%%","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]`

where `%%URL%%` is the desired URL.

Have a look at the following:

- [Getting google +1 Page shares via AJAX (hidden Api)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524077/getting-google-1-page-shares-via-ajax-hidden-api/21866500#21866500)
- http://www.sharedcount.com/documentation.php

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a private API not intended for public use. It could change or disappear at anytime without warning.

Comment: From where is that API key generated... I went to google console couldn't find anything that is appropriate that fits for this category...

Comment: +1. Was searching where to get the API key and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21866500/440646. How does anyone get to know that only this key works?

Comment: The API requires a request header `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8`. The `key` query parameter is not required.